# Making an ellipsoid in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

How can I make an ellipsoid using NumPy?

I've got something like this for a sphere:

```
def sphere()
   R = 25
   xx, yy, zz = np.mgrid[:100, :100, :100]
   return ((xx - 50) ** 2 + (yy - 50) ** 2 + (zz - 50)) < R**2
```

I'd like to generalize this to an ellipsoid, that could ideally have any rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here, I am not sure if this is the [Ellipsoid](https://bitbucket.org/bryancole/raytrace/src/02a66fea3db3/raytrace/ellipsoids.py) class you need.

Comment: What package does `ellipsoid` come from?